# I'm to change color of <div> in javascript on mouseOver function.Where am i going wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css

sharing the code
Help me with the solution

```
<div id ="hus" onmouseover="mouseOver()" style="background-color:#00FFFF;width:120px;height:20px;padding:40px;"> HUSAIN </div>

    <script>
    function mouseOver() {
      var x = document.getElementById( "hus" );
      x.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    </script>
```

where am i going wrong????

Comment: Works for me, Chrome (newest)

Comment: Works for me on Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: It works(Chrome 46.0.2490.71 m,Mozilla 41.0.2)

Answer (score 0):

Your codes actually work. If you mean the font-color, add this - (x.style.color = "blue";). There's nothing wrong with your syntax. But if it's with file extension, make it's ".html".

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. My previous answer is incorrect. Your syntax should be like this:

For the background:
x.style.background = "red";

For the color of the text/font:
x.style.color = "blue";